# WCF swap service interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm new with WCF and still experimenting.

I have two ServiceContract like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFirst
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void First();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ISecond
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Second();
}
```

On server side Client class implementing those interfaces:

```
public class Client : IFirst, ISecond
{
    static int count = 0;
    int id;

    public Client()
    {
        count++;
        id = count;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} client created.", id);
    }

    public void First()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First from: " + id.ToString());
    }

    public void Second()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second: " + id.ToString());
    }
}
```

and host:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Client), new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8000"));
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFirst), binding, "");
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISecond), binding, "");
host.Open();
```

On client side:

```
ChannelFactory<IFirst> firstFactory = new ChannelFactory<IFirst>(new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8000"));
IFirst iFirst = firstFactory.CreateChannel();
iFirst.First();

ChannelFactory<ISecond> secondFactory = new ChannelFactory<ISecond>(new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8000"));
ISecond iSecond = secondFactory.CreateChannel();
iSecond.First();
```

This works fine. It calls First and then Second method but for each call creates new instance of Client class. It is obvious because when client creates channel, service creates new instance of Client object. What I wish to achieve is call Second after First but for the same instance of Client. Is it even possible? I know I can put this two methods in one service but it is not what I wish for.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you want to call the two methods while creating only one client.
In WCF you can control Instancing by setting InstanceContextMode property of Service Behavior Attribute. There are three possible values 
-PerCall
-PerSession
-Single

You can use PerSession as it keeps the object active for the next calls from client.
The object is released when the session ends

You can decorate your class
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

At first I was a little confused by you calling your Service Implementation "Client" :P

But anyway, by default, WCF uses InstanceContextMode.PerCall, which means that it will instantiate a new Service implementation instance for every request into the Service.

If you want for subsequent service calls to be handled within the same service instance, you will have to use either PerSession or Single InstanceContextModes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx summarises Sessions, Instances and Concurrency in WCF pretty well.